# Ho to reduce distance between non monotonic turnstile and its subscript

Tags: logic, turnstile

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\newcommand{\nc}{\,\mid\!\sim\,} 
\begin{document}
$A \nc_\mathscr{K} C$
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have `\mathscr{K}` closer to the Non monotonic turnstile (`\nc`)?

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of `\,` on either side of the symbol, which is already a relation symbol, so it has generous space around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one is willing to make the subscript syntax that of an optional argument, then this approach might work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,stackengine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\newcommand\nc[1][]{\def\stacktype{L}%
  \mathrel{{\mid}\mkern-3.5mu{\sim}\stackunder[.9\dp\strutbox]{}{$\!\scriptstyle#1$}}}
\begin{document}
$A \nc[\mathscr{K}] C\quad A \nc C\quad A \nc[x] C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any purpose in the thin spaces around the `\nc` symbol, which is a relation symbol, so TeX already provides for generous space (`\thickmuskip`) around it.

You have two problems: lowering the subscript, which is obtained by adding an empty superscript, and pushing it nearer the tilde.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nc}{e{^_}}{%
  \mid
  \mspace{-3.5mu}%
  \sim^{\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}%
      \IfValueT{#2}{_{\!#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A \nc C$\quad
$A \nc_{\mathscr{K}} C$\quad
$A \nc_{x} C$\quad
$A \nc_{y}^{P} C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

See edit history for an outdated version.